# How to put Row over Stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, row, scaffold

I have a Scaffold in the body of which there is a Stack that occupies all the space. I would like to place Row on top of Stack so that it is at the top of the screen. How can I do this?

```
  return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Row(    
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a column widget to achieve that

```
return Scaffold(
 body : Column(
   children: [
     Row(
       children: [],
    ),
    Stack(
     children: [],
    )
   ]
 )
)
```